# Looking for a zen place in the Thailand/Cambodia/Vietnam Area where I can be incredibly productive

Tags: thailand, southeast-asia, beaches, vietnam, cambodia

I'm a Software Developer and need to get away from all the noise to focus on a project. The only thing required is a good internet connection and fresh food. Beach would be nice. OK housing should be available although since I prefer to work in coffeshops and switch locations anyways, that is not too much of a requirement.

Can someone recommend a place?

Comment: You want to get away from all the noise, yet work in coffeeshops...?

Comment: Yeah i don't feel that a laidback coffeshop atmosphere at the beach is what i would refer to as "noise".

Answer (score 1):

I've been to Sihanoukville in Cambodia and stayed in a resort that was a decent way out of the town - great food, good service (it's run by Australians). Somewhat not useful in that I cannot remember the name of the hotel (so sorry!) but I recommend the coast of Cambodia, incredibly peaceful and cheap.